# Did I actually do something wrong here? If not, how do I get my question undeleted

Tags: discussion, rules

I asked what I thought was a perfectly reasonable question about lightroom.

[Is there a way to get lightroom to show me the camera's original thumbnail?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/43889/is-there-a-way-to-get-lightroom-to-show-me-the-cameras-original-thumbnail?noredirect=1)

Nobody answered it, and a little while later I wrote a lua script to solve my problem.   I answered my own question with a link to the script.  A little while later a moderator deletes my question saying:

"Sorry smoofra, but this is not an open forum for your personal advertising. Creating a question solely to answer it with a link to your own product is unacceptable. This and any future attempts will be deleted"

Here are the key points:

- I wrote the question before I wrote the script.
- The purpose of the script is to solve the problem posed by the question.   It isn't a product.   It isn't for sale.   Nobody is making any money off of it, and nobody ever will.

Did I do something wrong here?   This guy deletes my post and accuses me of being a spammer for asking an honest question  and sharing the answer I came up with.   I have to say its left a sour taste in my mouth with respect to this whole community.

Comment: I've reopened the question, the original close was in response to a flag on the answer so it may be worth updating it to reflect that in absence of a response, you rolled your own.

Comment: Keep in mind that we do get quite a bit of spam, and it's usually the case that when it looks suspicious, it actually _is_. Moderation keeps the site nice for all of us, but sometimes mistakes can be made. They can be fixed. No big deal.

Comment: And while I can understand the freaking out a bit, I promise you everyone here really is quite nice and reasonable, particularly the mods.  Misunderstandings do happen, but we're all pretty used to communicating and working it out when issues happen.  (And yes, I realize that isn't always, or even commonly, the case on the Interwebs.)

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your question, personally I think it looks like a legit thing that was just accidentally deleted as spam.  Best bet in these cases is to hit the flag and plead your case so that a moderator can un-delete it.  I think it looks fair to me since it is an open-source solution and was clearly done as a solution to the problem you were having based on the timing of the github commits.

Comment: Hit the flag?  What's that mean?   I couldn't find any way to appeal the delete.

Comment: @smoofra there should be a flag hyperlink below your post. It allows you to write a message to the moderator asking for moderation.